# KeyError when selecting specific values with two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

My database has data about different plants in different days and hours, and some calculation thhat were done on them.
I want to create "mini" datasets ,when each data set will contain data about different days and data.
for example:
dataset 1: all the plants, date:17/6, hour 12:00, Treatment, Line,NDVI.....

[image]

I have tried to do that using the code

```
df_07=df_indices[(df_indices['date']=='6/17/2019') & (df_indices['Hour'] > '12:00')]
```

but I keep get KeyError:

> KeyError: 'date'

I don't know why it doesn't recognize date, because as you can ssee in the image, it has the column date. Can it happen because i'm using 'date' as an index?

**My end goal is to create new tables that will have only one date and one hour for all the plants.**

Comment: The `date` column appears to actually be part of the index.

Comment: @CDJB how come? it looks like it's on top of the column, above the line. can you explain more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
m1 = (df_indices.index.get_level_values('date')=='6/17/2019')
```

For second mask convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and compare with [`Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html):

```
m2 = pd.to_timedelta(df_indices.index.get_level_values('Hour')+':00') > pd.Timedelta(12, 'h')

df_07=df_indices[m1 & m2]
```

Better solution is join `date` with `hour` level, so possible compare by `datetime`s:

**Sample data:**

```
df_indices = pd.DataFrame({'date':['6/17/2019','6/17/2019'],
                           'Hour':['15:00','10:00'],
                           'col':[4,5]}).set_index(['date','Hour'])


print (df_indices)
                 col
date      Hour      
6/17/2019 15:00    4
          10:00    5
```

---

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df_indices.index.get_level_values('date') + ' ' + 
                       df_indices.index.get_level_values('Hour'))
print (dates)
DatetimeIndex(['2019-06-17 15:00:00', '2019-06-17 10:00:00'], 
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)


df_07=df_indices[dates > '2019-06-17 12:00:00']
print (df_07)
                 col
date      Hour      
6/17/2019 15:00    4
```

Comment: I get the same error as before, that it ignores the '12:00' and only consider the first condition even though we have &

Comment: thanl you for the answer but first it has invalis syntax and second if you could say few words about this because I would like to understand what is your idea

Comment: @Reut - first `m2` was modified with remove `.dt` and last `)`

Comment: still syntax is invalid and I want to understand more your idea ,I am not sure why do we need 2 variables for that

Comment: @Reut - this is 2 alternative solutions for `m2` :)

Comment: unfortunatly i'm still getting syntax error, but could you please maybe explain me what do you think the problem is? why my original code doesn't work?

Comment: why do we have >12 on  m2?

Comment: @Reut - for me working nice, `>12` because more like 12 hours

Comment: I don't want 12 hours as quantitiy , but I want the hour 12 am

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203592/discussion-between-jezrael-and-reut).